# Composer.lock incompatibility with actually installed versions of packages on production server

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm working on a project based on PHP7 and Laravel. Unfortunately, there was a problem with dependencies and package versions.

I guessed that the previous developer working on the project started updating packages by calling

```
composer update
```

on his local dev environment.

Therefore, a new composer.lock file has been generated and everything has been pushed to the production server - however, the composer update command has not been called on the production...

There is a problem with the incompatibility of the PHP version and other errors in dependencies.

This is a very large project and I wouldn't like to migrate now to higher versions on the production server.

I am currently preparing a development environment and I care about maintaining the maximum compatibility of all package versions with what is on production.

By calling:

```
composer install
```

on local environment, I'm receiving a series of errors related to the incompatibility of the package versions.

Is there any way to regenerate / restore composer.json and composer.lock based on what is currently installed on the production server? Unfortunately, at this moment composer.lock on production doesn't completely reflect the current state of actually installed versions.

What is a safe and good way to recreate locally a cloned project from a repository on a production server - and maintain full compatibility of all package versions, the correct form of composer.json and composer.lock?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Don't you use source control like SVN or GIT ? Kind of impossible to revert to a previous version otherwise.

Comment: I received the project with only the production version code. Unfortunattely, I've no access to history of last commits. It was managed by a previous developer who didn't transfer anything to us.

Actually I'm creating new repository of project code, based on Gitlab.

Comment: Well your best bet is to try to determine the exact versions based on the production composer.lock and strictly specify them in the local composer.json (e.g. if there was "pacakage/name": "^1" you'd make it "package/name": "1.2.3" to get the exact working version you need) and run composer update again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to recreate `composer.json` file based on what is already installed in `/vendor`. You can look for `/vendor/composer/installed.json` file as a reference for installed versions of all packages.

What you need to do in this case is:

1. Make sure your local environment is exactly the same as your production one. You can fake it if needed in your `composer.json` too by using [platform configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform).
2. Your `composer.lock` file is of no use. Get `/vendor/composer/installed.json` file from your production. Delete your `/vendor` folder.
3. Run `composer install`. Write down all packages that have issues and check provided solutions by Composer.
4. Start downgrading the versions in your `composer.json` for packages that have issues based to the solutions provided by Composer. Be sure to look into those packages yourself - developers aren't always very strict with the way they maintain dependencies and versioning of their packages. You can always just take package version from production's `/vendor/composer/installed.json` and place that specific version in your `composer.json`.
5. Repeat steps 3-4 until you can finally generate new `composer.lock` file. Make sure your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files are tracked by your VCS and fixate the changes.

Answer (score 2):

To run `composer update` and `composer install`

You can run with this code

`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Or for update

`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

I found https://www.wuhaiqiao.com/2020/11/24/329.html

Comment: what is this command for `--ignore-platform-reqs`? I have faced same issue